# Passing default values to **kwargs

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

I have a function that returns some data, what I need to do in order to get the data is to pass an SQL-like query to the `build_query` variable.

```
def foo(client):
    """
    API service that returns JSON data and accepts arguments
    """
    report_query = (client.buildQuery()
                        .Select('Date','SearchEngine')
                        .From('Report_10')
                        .During('Yesterday')

    get_report.downloadReport(
            skip_header=True,
            include_names=False,
            get_summary=True,
            get_totals=False)
```

What I am trying to do is make this function in to one that accepts `**kwargs` but has default arguments for the selected fields.

The idea is that I would be able to pass an argument to `.During()` and if I don't it defaults to `Yesterday`, I would be able to pass arguments to `.Select()`, for example `.Select()` would be `.Select('Date','Device','StrategyType')`.

What I've tried and trying to understand:

```
def fn(**kwargs):
    print(f"""
    ({kwargs['client']}.buildQuery()
     .Select({kwargs['select']}))
     .From({kwargs['report_type']})
     .During({kwargs['during']})

     get_report.downloadReport(
            skip_header={kwargs['skip_header']},
            include_names={kwargs['include_names']},
            get_summary={kwargs['get_summary']},
            get_totals={kwargs['get_totals']})""")
```

```
fn(client='10',select=['Date', 'SearchEngine'],report_type='new',during='Yesterday',skip_header=True)
```

Returns:

```
 (10.buildQuery()
     .Select(['Date', 'SearchEngine']))
     .From(new)
     .During(Yesterday)

     get_report.downloadReport(
            skip_header=True,
            include_names=False,
            get_summary=True,
            get_totals=False)
```

Where I get stuck is trying to call `fn()` without any keyword arguments and wishing that the function would have default arguments for each field, such that it would look like the first code snippet in my question.

`fn()`

> KeyError: 'client'

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the spread operator on dictionaries:

```
def func(**kwargs):
    kwargs = {"printer": None, **kwargs}
```

This will set the value `printer` to none if it is not given.